# How to generate a custom unique key per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, linq-to-entities

I would like to generate a custom sequential key that should restart at every new financial year. I have provided a sample data with the mentioned `FinancialYear` and `CustomKey` columns.

Note: I want to ensure that the same value is not get during two or more attempts to add rows at same time.

Example Data :

```
ID    |   FinancialYear   |  CustomKey
1     |   2019            |  1
2     |   2019            |  2
3     |   2020            |  1
```

I'm open to any solution using Linq to Entities or SQL Server.

I already have a solution with triggers so please don't share any solution with them.

Comment: Any explanation from the person who decided to thumb this down? Would be appreciated.

Comment: The downvoters should know that this is a very common problem for any billing application.

Answer (score 1):

How about using max CustomKey + 1 ?

```
DECLARE @NextCustomKey AS INT = 0;

SELECT @NextCustomKey = ISNULL(MAX(CustomKey),0) + 1
FROM [TableName]
WHERE FinancialYear = 2019;

INSERT INTO [TableName] (
FinancialYear
,CustomKey
)
VALUES (
2019
,@NextCustomKey
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but what about concurrency ?

Comment: @AGH, The entire code to be wrapped by transaction with repeatable read or higher isolation, this is going to be your concurency

Comment: @AlexanderVolok As far as i know there can be duplicate custom key if number of user attempt to add row at same time.

Comment: @AGH not with an isolation level of repeatable read, in that isolation level your second user will be waiting until the first one has finished its transaction before getting a value. The problem is that it can slow your application (waiting for other users) and raise many deadlocks.

Comment: @MarcGuillot Thanks for explanation, will update my knowledge :)

Comment: @MarcGuillot May i know how do i rollback last increment value if transaction in fail.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I create a sequence for each partition (each year in this case), so I don't need to worry about concurrency (I had constants deadlocks and lags before using sequences due to the high isolation levels needed to prevent duplicating keys).

You can define an stored procedure to easily retrieve a new key (dynamically creating new sequences when necessary).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COUNTER_NewValue]
    @YEAR int, 
    @COUNTER int out
AS
  declare @Sequence nvarchar(64); 
  declare @SQL nvarchar(128);
BEGIN
  set @Sequence = N'CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_' + cast(@YEAR as nvarchar(64))

  if not exists(select * from sys.sequences where name = @Sequence) 
  begin
    set @SQL = N'create sequence dbo.' + @Sequence + ' as bigint start with 1';
    execute sp_executesql @SQL;
  end

  set @SQL = N'set @COUNTER = next value for dbo.' + @Sequence;
  exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@COUNTER int out', @COUNTER = @COUNTER out;
END
```

I have a similar procedure to change a sequence value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COUNTER_SetValue]
  @YEAR int,
  @COUNTER int
AS
declare @Sequence nvarchar(64)
declare @SQL nvarchar(128)
BEGIN
  set @Sequence = N'CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_' + cast(@YEAR as nvarchar(64));

  set @COUNTER = @COUNTER - 1;

  if not exists(select * from sys.sequences where name = @Sequence ) 
  begin
    set @SQL = N'create sequence dbo.' + @Sequence + ' as bigint start with ' + cast(@COUNTER as nvarchar(64));  
  end
  else
  begin
    set @SQL = N'alter sequence dbo.' + @Sequence + ' restart with ' + cast(@COUNTER as nvarchar(64));  
  end

  -- I have assigned @COUNTER - 1 to the sequence, and then increase it, so current_value of the sequence always contains the previous value that the sequence will return
  execute sp_executesql @SQL;

  exec COUNTER_NewValue @YEAR = @YEAR, @COUNTER = @COUNTER out;
END
```

Finally, for when a document is rolled back, I have the COUNTER_Rollback procedure, that will check if the sequence can be decreased (there are no new values), and decreases it to the last value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COUNTER_Rollback]
    @YEAR integer,
    @COUNTER integer
AS
  declare @LAST_COUNTER integer;
BEGIN
  -- If there are no new values greater thant the counter to rollback (the document rolled back was the last one), then we recalculate the counter

  if not exists (select * from MYTABLE where FinancialYear = @YEAR and CustomKey > @COUNTER)
  begin   
    select @LAST_COUNTER = isnull(max(CustomKey),0) + 1 from MYTABLE where FinancialYear = @YEAR;

    exec COUNTER_SetValue @YEAR = @YEAR, @COUNTER = @LAST_COUNTER;
  end
  else 
  begin
    throw 99001, 'The sequence can''t be rolled back beause there are new values and you''ll need to fill the holes manually', 1;
  end 
END
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i knew about sequence but logic didn't come in my mind. However, I am going to try this and let you know.

Comment: I cannot rollback sequence as doesn't support transactions. I can  alter sequence in exception block if any error occurs but its not good idea because in that moment other connection generate next value. Please share any suggestion if you have.

Comment: @AGH rolling back actions doesn't have an easy solution, because, as you say, other users may have already generated their own new values, so you get a hole in your numeration and you can't just decrease your counter. Personally I check if my value is the last value and only in that case I decrease the sequence, but if there already were another value, then you must fill the hole manually. I will update the answer showing all my procedures.

Comment: @AGH I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about below solution?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.CustomKeyTbl') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE CustomKeyTbl
END
Create table CustomKeyTbl(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FinancialYear INT, CustomKey INT)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CustomKeyInsert
@Year INT
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @CustomKey INT

 SELECT @CustomKey = 
    ISNULL(MAX(CustomKey),0) + 1
 FROM CustomKeyTbl
 WHERE FinancialYear = @Year

 INSERT INTO CustomKeyTbl(FinancialYear,CustomKey)
 SELECT @Year,@CustomKey

 END

 Exec CustomKeyInsert 2018
```

I am not sure you are going to insert data in bulk or single row at a time. In case of single record above code should be fine. In case of bulk load we need to convert procedure parameter to be varchar and values should be passed as csv. After that convert csv to table and make appropriate changes to actual logic.

Comment: Thanks but it will raise many deadlock and will down system.

Comment: @AGH To handle concurrency you can add one more column with rowversion datatype.

Comment: Rowverison may not help me to generate sequence number.

Comment: I already mentioned you can use rowversion to handle concurrency not to generate sequence number.